# Dynamically added Components in TopComponent won't show

Tags: java, swing, refresh, netbeans-platform

I'm running in a quite strange problem while programming with the Netbean platform 7.3, based on Geertjan's blog example on how to add widgets through actions (https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/add_widget_via_action_in) :

I created a TopComponent, and I want it to show a custom ScrollPane rendering images in a custom pane. My custom Scrollpane is working nice in a basic Java Swing application.

I tried to display the Scrollpane in the TopComponent's constructor, just to test :

```
  public TopComponent()
    {
        super();
        setBackground( Color.BLUE );
        initComponents();
        setName( Bundle.CTL_Scanmage2TopComponent() );
        setToolTipText( Bundle.HINT_Scanmage2TopComponent() );
        setImage( ImageHandlerFactory.getImageHandler( new File( ... ) ));
    }
```

There is the setImage method the `ImageHandler` is a class of mine describing an image :

```
public void setImage( ImageHandler handler ) throws Exception
{
    pane = new Scrollpane(); // pane is a class field of type : Scrollpane

    pane.setImage( handler ); // thats OK, the tiled image is loaded, etc.

    setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

    add( pane , BorderLayout.CENTER , 0 );

    pane.revalidate(); // does not work
    pane.repaint(); // does not work
}
```

All OK, the netbeans application launches, the image is well displayed in the application *only when setImage is called from constructor or from componentOpened*.

Now, I would load the image through a menu, I implemented an interface, a service provider, all OK.

From the menu action, I use the lookup to find all objects having the method to load the image through the ImageHandler generated from this action.

Then, calling `setImage(...)` through the Lookup does nothing, my TopComponent absolutely refuses to display anything.

I tried to use a `FlowLayout`, thus displaying a small (about 3x3 pix) thing in the top of the TopComponent.

The question is : how can I force the TopComponent to paint the Scrollpane (extends JScrollpane) I put into it ?

I tried to revalidate / validate / invalidate / repaint / ... the TopComponent, the Scrollpane, but no way...

Any idea ?

Thanks !

**-- EDIT 1 / reedited : unuseful parts deleted --**

Geertjan's app still works fine, but calling the setImage method from the button's action does nothing.

Here is the code of this button :

```
public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
{
    Lookup.Result<MyInterface > controllers = Lookup.getDefault().lookupResult( MyInterface .class );
    Collection<? extends MyInterface > controllersColl = controllers.allInstances();
    for( MyInterface c : controllersColl )
    {
        c.setImage( imgH ); // debug shows it passes heres and expected internal job is done
    }
}
```

All seems to go OK, objects are created, etc. but nothing visible happens in the GUI.

**-- EDIT 2 / reedited : unuseful parts deleted --**

**-- EDIT 3 / after Tan Hui Onn answer --**

Indeed, that was it, thanks Tan Hui Onn : "you will just get another instance of TopComponent".

Using `TopComponent.getRegistry().getActivated()` does the job.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: For some reasons (code volume and confidentiality of some parts of the code), I cannot post a full SSCCE, that worries me a lot. Thus, I can post parts of code if you tell me in which direction to look for. Also, thanks for the edit.

Comment: Just the parts needed to show the problem.  But make them into an SSCCE.

Comment: I will try to do that quickly. Thank you for following the problem.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I added some code to show the problem, Geertjan's example and my small mod are IMHO relevant of the problem.

Comment: Be as humble as you like.  I will not give this further attention until there is an SSCCE posted.

Comment: I understand your POV, I will try to do this in the week. I managed to make Geertjan's example work with my component, but I really would you to have a look at it in order to explain me where I did something wrong.

Comment: *"I really would you to have a look at it"*  Then really tell me when there is an SSCCE.  I don't spend my time eyeballing uncompilable code snippets (unless I am being paid an inordinate amount of money to do so).

Comment: Oh yes, I was meaning "a look at the SSCCE I will post in the week". Sorry for the inconvenience, I wrote it in an inappropriate manner.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'd have a few moment to build the SSCCE, I put it into the answer in EDIT 2. I propose to delete some comments here, do you agree ?

Comment: *"have a few moment to build the SSCCE, I put it into the answer in EDIT 2"*  ?!?  That is a Zip file containing over 350 **files,** whereas an SSCCE would be one source file of ..somewhat less than 350 **lines** of code!  Did you even *read* the linked article?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Let me explain : I know what a SSCCE is, I just wanted to post something ready to run/debug into NB, while keeping a structure near the origin. The actual project is far more complex, I cutted/bypassed/mocked a lot of code. I renamed the two entry points with obvious names : 'OpenFileActionWhichDontWork.java' and 'OpenFileActionWhichWorks.java' to easily see what happens. Let me know what you want me to do, I'm always ready to do better when possible.

Comment: *"Let me know what you want me to do"*  This is really not about what I want.  Since it is your question & your problem, I have only a passing technical interest in it.  My point it that if ***you*** want better help, post an SSCCE.  And by 'SSCCE', I mean an **SSCCE** - a single source short enough to post directly to the question.  If you cannot manage that, I can be of no further help..  Re. *"I know what a SSCCE is"*  It is quite apparent that you don't, otherwise you'd not have wasted my time (and patience) in posting a link to a ****ing Zip file!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can get the opened TopComponent through @ServiceProvider. I think you will just get another instance of TopComponent.

For testing, I add this line `((ImageDisplayerCapability) MyModuleTopComponent.getRegistry().getActivated()).setImage(imgH);` in OpenFileActionWhichDontWork.actionPerformed. It shows something (but I am not sure it is correct or not).